# Un panino freddo

Tags: word-usage, idioms

Stavo usando Busuu correggendo qualche esercizio di persone che stanno imparando l'italiano e mi sono imbattuto in una persona che, durante una simulazione di una interazione in un bar, chiedeva di avere "panino freddo".

Ora, a mio parere, non è grammaticalmente sbagliato,   né semanticamente sbagliato, ma non riesco a capire perché mi suona una frase strana. Se penso a come io farei passare il messaggio, aggiungerei un "senza riscaldarlo" o aspetterei di ricevere la domanda "te lo riscaldo?" dal barista.

È la mia sensazione sbagliata o effettivamente c'è qualcosa che non va? Se sì, cosa?

Edit: Per chiarire, l'altra persona è spagnola e la frase completa dell'esercizio è "Buongiorno, vorrei un panino freddo e, da bere, una bottiglia grande di acqua frizzante, grazie".

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE! Anch'io usai Busuu anni fa e imparai tantissimo grazie alle persone che, come te, correggevano i miei esercizi.

Comment: Sono d'accordo; così, fa pensare a un prodotto raffreddato di proposito, come il tè freddo.

Comment: Si tratta probabilmente di una traduzione letterale dalla lingua della persona che ha fatto l'esercizio. Nelle mie lingue, quando si va in un bar nel mio paese, è solito vedere un elenco di "bocadillos fríos" (cast.) o "entrepans freds" (cat.) e un altro di "bocadillos calientes" (cast.) o "entrepans calents" (cat.).  Poi, come ha detto @DaG, "bocadillos fríos" o "entrepans freds" non sono panini raffreddati nel frigo, si tratta semplicemente di panini imbottiti che non si riscaldano e si servono a temperatura ambiente.

Comment: La tua domanda, quindi, è se quell'espressione è grammaticalmente corretta? Mi verrebbe da dire di sì, però perlomeno scrivici la frase intera. Per esempio, c'è un articolo davanti a "panino freddo"? Perché "avere panino freddo" sicuramente è sbagliato.

Comment: Nota, poi, che esistono frasi che sono grammaticalmente corrette ma non idiomatiche, questo è perfettamente normale e non dovrebbe stupirti. Per esempio se vai in un bar e chiedi dell'"acqua con le bollicine" o "acqua con anidride carbonica", entrambe le espressioni sono grammaticalmente corrette ma non idiomatiche perché in italiano si preferisce dire "acqua frizzante" o "acqua gassata".

Comment: @FedericoPoloni ho aggiunto la frase completa, anche se in ogni caso avevo già specificato che è grammaticalmente corretta. Secondo me ha ragione DaG, c'entra il fatto che il panino è naturalmente freddo, a differenza del tè.

Comment: @Charo beh, in effetti l'altra persona è spagnola, quindi direi che siamo sulla strada giusta :D

Comment: @DaG: Vorresti scrivere una risposta? Sentiti libero di usare quello che ho scritto nel mio commento.

Comment: @bracco23: Allora, secondo me, si tratta di un problema di tipo culturale (le abitudini di un paese sono diverse da quelle di un altro) a cui si aggiunge una traduzione letterale dallo spagnolo: il risultato è un'espressione che risulta bizzarra in italiano.

Comment: Voglio dire che in Spagna (o perlomeno in Catalogna) si è arrivato alla consuetudine di concepire i panini imbottiti in modo da classificarli in queste due categorie ("fríos" e "calientes"), ma in Italia non credo sia così (non ne sono sicura, però).

Comment: Sinceramente non vedo alcunché di strano nella frase, anche considerando che una virgola dopo *freddo* la cambierebbe abbastanza. Mi pare che, in questo caso, parlare di idiomatico/non idiomatico sia un po' esagerato perché mischia il concetto d'idiomatico con le intenzioni del parlante. Se il parlante non ama i panini caldi, credo bene che possa dire "voglio un panino freddo".

Comment: @Charo c'entra il fatto che in molti casi i panini siano tenuti in frigo a 4 gradi (esistono leggi al proposito), ma non fa piacere mangiare un panino così freddo. Spesso il ristoratore chiede "lo scaldo un po'?" ma, *se non lo chiede*, è un problema. E poi può succedere che il panino risulti bollente fuori e congelato dentro, se scaldato troppo in fretta. Non è semplice!

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica:  Il problema è che, se la persona che ha fatto l'esercizio è spagnola, probabilmente non ha in mente un panino raffreddato a 4°C.

Comment: Non ho capito; ma quindi in soldoni la domanda qual è, visto che dici che sai già che è quell'espressione è grammaticalmente corretta e che non è idiomatica?

Comment: Beh, @bracco23... se continui a fare correzioni di esercizi di persone che stanno imparando l'italiano su Busuu, magari di tanto in tanto potresti dire loro che qui hanno un sito in cui possono porre domande sulla lingua :)

Comment: @Charo se capita l'occasione sicuramente ;)

Answer (score 5):

Confermo che ordinare “un panino freddo” non ha nulla di “sbagliato”, dal punto di vista grammaticale o altro. La questione è solo che se un madrelingua italiano ordina un panino e lo desidera così come è esposto nel bancone del bar senza farselo scaldare, in genere non gli verrà in mente di usare le parole “un panino freddo”: in questo senso non è quindi un modo idiomatico per formulare l'ordinazione. Un'espressione così farebbe pensare a un ipotetico prodotto consistente in un panino espressamente raffreddato, così come il tè freddo è costituito da tè messo in frigorifero dopo essere stato preparato.

Se proprio il parlante volesse sottolineare che il panino non va scaldato – per esempio perché sa che in quel bar li scaldano sempre senza chiedere conferma, o perché in genere se lo fa scaldare ma quel giorno no – probabilmente si esprimerebbe in un altro modo. Direbbe che panino vuole e aggiungerebbe “Non me lo scaldi, per favore / Me lo dia così com'è” (o in mille altri possibili modi).

<sub>Metto “sbagliato” tra virgolette perché la linguistica moderna non prescrive che cosa è giusto e cosa è sbagliato; studia i fenomeni linguistici come altre scienze studiano le specie di insetti o i fenomeni subatomici. Quello che potremmo dire, volendo, è che “un panino freddo”, in questo contesto, sia pragmaticamente “sbagliato”, cioè non corrispondente alle attese dell'interlocutore o degli altri parlanti presenti.</sub>

È possibile, ma non essenziale ai fini del valutare l'uso dell'espressione, che in chi ha pronunciato questa frase si sia verificata una contaminazione con la propria lingua madre, visto che – come segnala @Charo – in castigliano e in catalano è usuale chiamare un certo tipo di panini *bocadillos fríos* (cast.) o *entrepans freds* (cat.) e un altro tipo *bocadillos calientes* (cast.) o *entrepans calents* (cat.).

Answer (score 0):

A mio parere, la frase

> Buongiorno, vorrei un panino freddo e, da bere, una bottiglia grande di acqua frizzante, grazie.

non ha niente di sbagliato. I commenti sotto la domanda dicono che non si chiede un panino freddo perché i panini sono naturalmente freddi: allora è bizzarro chiedere un "buon caffè" o un "caffè bello caldo"? Il fatto che la persona che parla sia spagnola, e perciò ha in mente una distinzione tra panini caldi e freddi che in Italia è ritenuta non comune, è irrilevante, per diversi motivi.

Il primo è che la distinzione *potrebbe esserci*, dipende dal ristoratore e dal tipo di panino: un panino con vitello tonnato probabilmente non si scalda, ma uno con prosciutto e formaggio può essere preferito caldo o freddo anche secondo la temperatura del momento e soprattutto i gusti dell'avventore.

Il secondo motivo è che non credo che si debba fare un'analisi della bizzaria di una frase secondo la nazionalità di chi la dice. Allora una frase sarebbe non idiomatica se detta da uno spagnolo, ma perfettamente normale se pronunciata da un cinese?

Il terzo motivo riguarda il significato di *idiomatico*. La sua definizione (es. http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/idiomatico) non dice molto sulle implicazioni. La spiegazione di wikipedia è più utile (https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frase_idiomatica) perché ne cita una:

> locuzione di significato peculiare proprio di una specifica lingua, la cui traduzione letterale in altre lingue può non aver senso logico

Esempi di tali frasi sono "prendere Roma per toma", "andare a ramengo", "avere le mani in pasta". Nel caso di "panino freddo" non esiste questo tipo di ambiguità, la frase significa esattamente quello che dice, *non è idiomatica*.

Si può pensare allora di prendere la definizione di *idiomatico* al contrario, cioè dire che "panino freddo" non è idiomatico e quindi è strano. Ma ritengo che questo ragionamento sia sbagliato, in questo caso. Sarebbe giusto se, dato un concetto da esprimere, si scegliesse una frase che normalmente non si usa perché una frase fatta per tale concetto già esiste ed è molto comune; per esempio per dire che si va a mangiare cena con Mario a casa sua, si potrebbe dire (esempio tratto da un commento recente in un altro post):

> Vado a mangiare nella casa di Mario

che effettivamente è corretta ma non comune; le scelte più ovvie di un madrelingua italiano sarebbero

> Vado a mangiare da Mario
>   Vado a mangiare a casa di Mario

Quindi, per concludere, se una persona desidera ordinare un panino freddo (e i motivi potrebbero essere diversi), non può che dire "voglio un panino freddo". La frase è corretta in tutti gli aspetti che riguardano la lingua italiana, e continuerebbe a esserlo anche se, per proclama del Re, fosse vietato ordinare panini freddi: intendo dire che la grammatica italiana prescinde da altri ambiti e le discussioni sull'Italiano dovrebbero fare altrettanto.

Comment: Mi sembra che questa risposta travisi il senso della domanda. È chiaro che, se uno vuole esplicitamente un panino freddo, è liberissimo di chiedere un panino freddo, come può chiederlo incartato in sette tovaglioli o porto con la mano sinistra. La questione è che se un madrelingua italiano ordina un panino, e lo desidera così come è esposto nel bancone del bar senza farselo scaldare, in genere non userà le parole “un panino freddo”.

Comment: @dag non mi pare proprio di aver travisato: l'OP dice "mi sembra strana": qui parliamo di lingua italiana o di "comportamenti italiani"? Ci stiamo chiediamo perché l'avventore specifica che vuole il panino freddo, oppure perché sceglie le parole "panino freddo"?

Comment: Comunque, come ti è già stato chiesto, scrivi tu una risposta; così esprimi il tuo punto di vista nella sede più opportuna.

Comment: È difficile tenere nettamente distinti la lingua italiana e i comportamenti italiani. La lingua è strettamente legata ai comportamenti. Se chiedo della “pizza rossa” mi capiscono tutti perché è usuale preparare un certo tipo di pizza chiamata così; se chiedo della “pizza verde” non commetto nessuna improprietà linguistica, ma di fatto quello che dico non ha un significato identificabile, né più né meno che se usassi una parola inesistente.

Comment: Sono d'accordo sulla digressione sull'idiomaticità, non è una espressione idiomatica o meno, e di certo sapere la lingua madre di chi parla aiuta a capire perché si è scelti una particolare espressione, senza però questo influenzare quanto tale espressione sia adatta o meno alla lingua e alla cultura di destinazione.

Comment: Non sono d'accordo sugli esempi relativi al caffè: chiedere un caffè non implica che sia buono o molto caldo, quindi chiedere un "buon caffè" o un "caffè bello caldo" aggiunge qualcosa che chi ascolta non necessariamente assume di suo. Se invece chiedessi un "caffè caldo", direi qualcosa che chi ascolta avrebbe assunto essere vero anche se non l'avessi detto. Un "caffè" è un "caffè caldo", a meno che io non dica altrimenti.

Comment: Alla fine penso che la questione scenda nel fatto che, a meno che non ci sia un motivo particolare, si tende ad evitare aggettivi che sarebbero sintatticamente corretti ma "ridondanti" nel senso che descrivono proprietà che l'ascoltatore avrebbe assunto essere presenti in ogni caso.

Comment: @bracco23 è vero, l'esempio del caffè è un po' tirato, cercavo un parallelo con qualche cosa che solitamente è caldo. Forse con il tè funziona meglio, ma le due frasi "mi faccia un tè caldo" e "vorrei un tè caldo" mi fanno pensare.